# Bring back Master database from Single_user to Multi_user mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Over the weekend, one of our colleagues applied the latest patch SQL 2012 SP3 CU8. But when we came in this morning 'master' database is in Single_User mode.

I did tried the steps mentioned in this blog https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0e27bf0e-97df-4d2b-aa9d-e887b5b61504/master-database-in-single-usermode?forum=sqldatabaseengine by backing up the master database and restore it with different name, then changing to Multi_user mode and finally changing the file names, before restarting the service.

But it didn't work for me.

Also, checked the startup parameters and it doesn't have the -m parameter (single instance mode)

Any ideas?

Notes: Here is the error log snippet..

[image]

Comment: it is unclear for me if you actually stopped the service, then replaced the old master files by the new ones?

Comment: @George K sorry, yes I did stopped service, before replacing the files. Basically, I followed the steps from that blog.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is similar, but thought I'd share - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/96GYTbO4Ez0

Comment: @Naveen, Could you tell me , what is showing after execution of " exec sp_who2;". what it showing DBName.

Comment: Run through the steps again in the MSDN forum post, but before you restart the instance, confirm the master_copy database is actually set to multi_user mode via `select name, user_access_desc from sys.databases WHERE name like '%master%'`.  I wonder if something happened where the restored copy of the master db wasn't in multi_user mode when you swapped the files.